# React-redux - nested connected components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have created a simple react-redux app with a `<Parent />` and `<Child />` component, where both are connected to redux store ([working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-boilerplate-forked-qiqrm?file=/src/components/Parent.js) in CodeSandbox).

Upon initial render, the `<Parent />` component dispatches an action in its `componentWillMount()` lifecycle (same behaviour if the action was dispatched from its `constructor`)

The action sets the `status` state to ***pending*** in redux store. `<Child />` component has subscribed to this `status` state, but it only renders once during the initial render. I would assume that `<Child />` component would render at least 2 times. First time because of the initial render of its parent, and a second time when redux-state has changed. Am I missing something here? Does these two updates somehow get batched by react/redux?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount you should not use it. Redux is not async. I believe the cycle is run before the component is mounted hence it runs only once as the child is getting already new value.

Comment: You are right. Setting state, or in this case dispatching redux, in `componentWillMount` does not trigger additional render - I guess I read over the documentation a bit too fast.

Comment: for completeness sake: use `componentDidMount`. `componentWillMount` is deprecated (for years now) and will be removed in future versions of react.

Comment: The project uses react v. 16.3. I know that documentation advises against `componentWillMount` usage, but as long as the react version in this particular project is not upgraded, it should be fine to dispatch actions in `componenWillMount` -